# Splitting a string using a delimiter in Groovy and avoiding IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovy-console

I want to split an input parameter `inputDetails` to unit level. I'm using tokenize for doing this. Here is my code:

Groovy Code:

```
def inputDetails = "1234-a0-12;1111-b0-34";
def cDesc = inputDetails.tokenize(";");
for (int i=0; i<cDesc.size(); ++i)
{
    def cVer = cDesc.get(i);
    def cNum = cVer.tokenize("-");
    def a = cNum.get(0);
    def b = cNum.get(1);
    def c = cNum.get(2);

    println (" DEBUG : Input details are, ${a} : ${b} : ${c} \n");
}
```

Output:

```
 DEBUG : Input details are, 1234 : a0 : 12 

 DEBUG : Input details are, 1111 : b0 : 34
```

This output is correct and expected. But if I change the first line of Groovy code to following:

```
def inputDetails = "1234-a0-12;1111-b0";
```

I get following error message:

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java_util_List$get$6.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:9)
```

How can I fix it to prevent getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while supporting both, `1234-a0-12;1111-b0-34` and `1234-a0-12;1111-b0` inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Groovy's [multiple assignment](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multiple_assignment) feature to safely grab 3 values from the second tokenization. Consider following example:

```
def inputDetails = "1234-a0-12;1111-b0-34"

def cDesc = inputDetails.tokenize(";")

cDesc.each { part ->
    def (p1, p2, p3) = part.tokenize('-')

    println "DEBUG: Input details are, ${p1} : ${p2} : ${p3}"
}
```

Output:

```
DEBUG: Input details are, 1234 : a0 : 12
DEBUG: Input details are, 1111 : b0 : 34
```

The good thing is that this approach prevents `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NullPointerException`. If we change the first line to

```
def inputDetails = "1234-a0-12;1111-b0"
```

the result is:

```
DEBUG: Input details are, 1234 : a0 : 12
DEBUG: Input details are, 1111 : b0 : null
```

Comment: Thanks Szymon for making the problem statement more meaningful and the proposed solution.

Comment: It's a missed opportunity that the original authors of groovy didn't decide on `froody` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string into a 2D list by further splitting on '-':

```
def inputDetails = "1234-a0-12;1111-b0-34"
def elements = inputDetails.split(';').collect{it.split('-')}
```

`elements` is of type `List<List<String>>`. When printed, it yields:

```
[[1234, a0, 12], [1111, b0, 34]]
```

With this, you can afford more flexibility instead of hard-coding array indexes.

And with `"1234-a0-12;1111-b0"`, it's split into `[[1234, a0, 12], [1111, b0]]`

Comment: Hi Ernest, Your suggestion of splitting into a 2D array works but the result is an array form of my input: [[1234, a0, 12], [1111, b0, 34]]. I want to use each of the elements for a different purpose, how do i get 1234, a0, 12.. as seperate elements.

Comment: @Yash It's just a normal list of lists. You can just do a for-each: `elements.each{list -> def a = list[0]; def b = list[1], }...` and you can check the length of the list to know how many elements it contains.

Comment: Thanks for your help!